# Class to update lookup failing

Tags: apex

I have a class where i am trying to update 2 lookup fields if they exist.  I keep getting an error where it states the fields do not exist.  Is my for loop incorrect?

```
public set<id> planId = new Set<id>();
public set<id> projId = new Set<id>();
public list<Action_Item__c> pl;
public list<Action_Item__c> pj;
public list<Project__c> lu;
public list<Planning_Application__c> lu2;


public void initialize(String sObjectName) {
        if (!Trigger.isDelete) {
            for (SObject ids : Trigger.new) {
                Action_Item__c action = (Action_Item__c) ids;
                if (action.Planning_Application__c != null) {
                    planId.add(action.Planning_Application__c);
                }
                if (action.Project_ID__c != null) {
                    projId.add(action.Project_ID__c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

 public void bulkAfter() {
        if (!Trigger.isDelete) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                lu = [
                    SELECT
                        Id,
                        Name
                    FROM Project__c
                    WHERE id IN :projId
                ];
            }
        }
        if (!Trigger.isDelete) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                lu2 = [
                    SELECT
                        Id,
                        Name
                        FROM Planning_Application__c
                    WHERE id IN :planId
                ];
            }
        }

    }


 public void afterInsert(SObject so) {
    List<Project__c> newproject = lu;
    List<Planning_Application__c> newaplan = lu2;

    For(Project__c newproj : newproject){
    for (Action_Item__c act1 : newproj.Action_Items__r)
    {
        if (newproj.Project_ID__c != null) {
            act1.Project_ID__c = newproj.Project_ID__c;
        }
    }
    }
    
    For(Planning_Application__c newpl : newplan){
            for (Action_Item__c act2 : newpl.Actions__r)
        {
            act2.Planning_Application__c = newpl.Planning_Application__c;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to access variables on a list, rather than a single sObject.

```
    for (Action_Item__c act1 : newaction1)
    {
        if (newaction1.Project_ID__c != null) {  --- does not exist
            act1.Project_ID__c = newaction1.Project_ID__c;  --- does not exist
        }
    }
```

`newaction1` is a `List<Action_Item__c> newaction1`. You seem to be going for `act1.Project_ID__c`.

Comment: Hey @David Reed.  I had my initial queries wrong.  I needed to get the id, name from the Project__ and Planning_Application__c objects. When a user creates an action_item record while on the project__c or Planning_Application__c object I want to populate the project and Planning_Application__c lookup on the newly created action_item record.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your queries. It's just a switch to the wrong variable name, as above.

Comment: I have updated my class.  If I am trying to populate the new child record lookup field from a parent, don't I need to loop through the parent record first and then the child.  But I am unable to reference the parent record.  So newpl.Planning_Application__c variable doe snot exist.  But did I not assign the newpl 
 variable as an object?